# Is there a switch/case method in Processing program language?

Tags: switch-statement, processing

I am learning to program in Processing, and have a use for a switch/case statement. Does this exist already or, if not, is there a standard way to introduce it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [switch](http://www.processing.org/reference/switch.html).  This should cover all the typical uses you can apply any other `switch` statement to.

Comment: Thank you @abiessu for the information. I am using the book "Processing" by Casey Reas and Ben Fry, where I could not find switch in the contents or the index. It seems a strange omission from such a comprehensive book. It did not occur to me that it might be in the official reference even though they had not included it. Thanks again.